# When to answer amen and others and when not to?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, amen

If you're in the middle of pisukei dezimra, birchat hamazon, berachot of shema, birkat levanah etc, when are you allowed to respond amen, Baruch uvaruch shemo, aleychem shallom, etc?

Is there a simple rule to follow or is it different for each and every case?

Comment: the Sefer Avnei Yashfei has many charts throughout his Shu"t regarding this

Comment: At the back of the new, red, hebrew only Tehillas Hashem printed by Kehos, there is a full chart of permitted responses.

Comment: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5763/yisro.html